# Need a resource for creative writing

Tags: fiction, resources, creative-writing

I'm already quite good at writing and putting together words and sentences. However, I would like to improve myself to the level that I can write a nice entertaining novel or several short stories to comprise a volume.

Now I need an online resource (preferably e-book or PDF or Word document or PPT presentation) that teaches me the rules of writing...in BRITISH ENGLISH!

Yes, you heard me right, any resource from UK would be nice as I like to study in British English (all my favourite authors are British, Alistair Maclean, Ian Fleming, JRR Tolkien, Terry Pratchett, etc.).

So any help for a resource location would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little concerned about this, as it appears to be a list question, something not allowed on Stack Exchange sites. However, we have several other questions here along these lines, but nothing specific to British English.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're asking: are you asking for a guide to correct writing British writing style? Or are you asking for any book about any topic in creative writing... as long as the book is written in UK English?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer! @Standback - yes I need a book that is kind of like a guide in creative writing but written in British English.

Comment: And why -3 already? I'm not allowed to ask questions on this site?

Comment: Of course you're allowed; the problem is that the question is skirting close to two reasons to close. (1) It's a list question, already stated as off-topic by a mod. You're asking, "May I have a list of books?" (2) It's both a little too broad ("I need a book about creative writing") and little too narrow ("but it has to be specifically about British writing"). If you want to learn the differences between various dialects of English, read books from various English-speaking countries and compare them. Take notes and then try to apply that to your own writing. *Goheno anim.*

Comment: I wouldn't call this off-topic - it's about writing, after all  - but it it a little too broad. Maybe there's some way of narrowing this down some? There's nothing wrong with asking for resources, it'd just be nice to maybe target this a bit more. I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Thanks Neil! Alright maybe the question was a bit broad, but if somebody can tell me what it SHOULD have been like I will try not to repeat the same mistake in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules of writing, you say? From a British source, and more than that a good and respected writer?
I give to you, George Orwell's essay, Politics and the English Language:

http://www.resort.com/~prime8/Orwell/patee.html

You will find therein six rules for writing which I consider to be fairly useful; honestly you don't want to take anything too prescriptive as a guide, because to write anything good you will need to find your own voice.

Answer (score 1):

Although not British English, this website is great:
http://thewritepractice.com/

You can check *14 prompts* under Resources. They often publish blog posts with a certain theme and ask the readers to write about a theme for 15 minutes and then post it in the comments. They even have a monthly contest for a short story and the winner gets to be printed.